# npm install on application created with Create React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I created an app with Create React App, and all is working fine. I'm now trying to `npm install` to a new folder and it doesn't work. I would like to test this so I could make this App sources available and don't have to include the `node_modules` folder.

I get hundreds of errors `npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'filename'`. Filenames are usually like `\node_modules\.staging\lodash._reinterpolate-bad2da18\LICENSE.txt`.

And in the end `cb() never called!`.

I tried `npm cache clean` and deleting the `package-lock.json` as well. Same result.

I'm using fresh installed npm 6.14.8 and node v14.15.1

Comment: it would be helpful if you share a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the culprit: Avast somehow thought npm.cmd was a virus. I have added an exception and all is solved.